# For loop not ending when condition is met

Tags: java, for-loop

I've got code that reads user input for the size of an array of integers, that then reads user input for each integer. I'm running into trouble in that the array that reads each integer isn't stopped when the condition of the for loop is met (i < setSize). It just runs and runs and runs after I enter unlimited integer values. What could be going wrong. I need to have the set size be accepted in one option and the integer values be accepted in another option.

````
        int setSize = 0;
        int [] integerValues = new int[0];

        while (true){
            //read set size (number of integers)
            if (option == 1){
                //read user input for set size
                System.out.println("Enter set size:");
                setSize = scan.nextInt();
                //set integer values to be the size of set size
                integerValues = new int[setSize];

                mainMenu();
                option = sc.nextInt();
            }
            //Read set elements (integer values)
            else if (option == 2){

                //assign int values to array
                for (int i = 0; i < setSize; i ++){
                    System.out.println("Enter integer values:");
                    integerValues [i] = scanner.nextInt();
                }
            } ```
````

Comment: Why `option = sc.nextInt()`? Is this from some separate input (System.in should use a single scanner)? Further, when your `for` loop ends, it looks like `option` is still 2, and you hit the `while(true)` (so the loop repeats, and the `for` loop is reached again). You need either a `break` or just removing the `while` loop entirely. If this is for a menu control, you need to be prompting after delegating to some sub-menu.

Comment: please include a [mre] in the question, to avoid lots of guessing

Comment: Can you provide more of the code?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using 3 separate *Scanner* objects.  This shouldn't be necessary, here.

Here is a basic example of requesting input, and populating an *int* array.

```java
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter set size:  ");
int[] values = new int[scanner.nextInt()];
System.out.print("Enter integer values:  ");
for (int index = 0; index < values.length; index++)
    values[index] = scanner.nextInt();

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(values));
```

Example input, and output.

```
Enter set size:  10
Enter integer values:  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
```

Additionally, if you wanted to enter a value one at a time, you can use the following—a slight modification.

```java
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter set size:  ");
int[] values = new int[scanner.nextInt()];
for (int index = 0; index < values.length; index++) {
    System.out.printf("Enter value %d:  ", index + 1);
    values[index] = scanner.nextInt();
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(values));
```

```
Enter set size:  5
Enter value 1:  1
Enter value 2:  2
Enter value 3:  3
Enter value 4:  4
Enter value 5:  5
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: I made all inputs one scanner object, but i am still facing the same issue. The set size variable must be saved to it's own variable because I have to print it out later. It looks like I did the rest right according to your code, so I'm still not sure why I'm having this issue.

Comment: @Brianna, I imagine there may be an error with _option = sc.nextInt()_, as you would have captured a value a few lines above, with _setSize = scan.nextInt()_.  So, the _Scanner_ will wait until a new value is entered.  Or not; I am unsure what _mainMenu()_ does.